# how to sort numbers in an array ignoring text in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

soo
I have a problem. I would like to sort a list, with an other list inside (which contains numbers and text) by numbers but if there are 2 same numbers then sort should not sort by text, in other words, let the sort skip text.

My code:

```
nums = [[4,'w'],[4,'a'],[2,'a']] 
print(sorted(nums))
```

Result:

```
[[2, 'a'], [4, 'a'], [4, 'w']]
```

What I want to have:

```
[[2, 'a'], [4, 'w'], [4, 'a']]
```

As you can see, in "what I want to have" the `[4,'w']` and `[4,'a']` have not changed places, but they have changed places during sorting

Please help me recieve "what I want to have"

And sorry for my bad English, I'm not an English native speaker

Comment: in any case, you just want to sort by the *first element* in each sublist. So something like `sorted(nums, key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right my bad, I'll edit post

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of lists, not a multidimensional array.
But this will do what you have asked.
x[0] will sort by first index of each list.

```py
nums = [[4,'w'],[4,'a'],[2,'a']]

foo = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: x[0])
print(foo)

[[2, 'a'], [4, 'w'], [4, 'a']]
```

Comment: yeah it kinda works, but what if I want to sort this: ```nums = [[4,6,'t'],[4,10,'c'],[2,3,'a']]``` it gives me this result: ```[[2, 3, 'a'], [4, 6, 't'], [4, 10, 'c']]``` and 10 is bigger than 6 so why 6 is on right and ten on left?

Comment: Because you are only sorting the first index of each list, which is what the [0] does.  
This is a totally different question you are asking now.  
I don't understand what you mean? 10 is not on the left of anything?

You can add multiple lambdas  ```foo = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))```
Or you can use ```operator.itemgetter``` as @Corralien suggested